# EntityFramework SaveChangesAsync Deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6

I have a Repository class that has SaveAsync method.

```
public async virtual Task<Result<int>> SaveAsync(T entity, ActionType actionType)
    {
        //some binding for return object

        try
        {
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //logging
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

And MVC controller class that calls SaveAsync method :

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var entity = //getting entity
        Repository.SaveAsync(entity, ActionType.Update).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Debugging hangs on Repository.SaveAsync(entity, ...) line. 
I have read [an article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) about Task.Result deadlock problems. But the solution on article doesn't work with my code.

---Updating question

```
protected override void OnSaveExecuted(UserGroup entity, Result<int> operationResult, ref ActionResult actionResult)
    {
        //Execute actions if UserGroup saving operation was successfully completed
        if (!operationResult.HasError)
        {//someactions

            operationResult = Repository.SaveAsync(entity, ActionType.Update).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        base.OnSaveExecuted(entity, operationResult, ref actionResult);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you await SaveAsync?

Comment: @NedStoyanov OnActionExecuted does not have async mark. ChildActions have same problem these does not support async/await.

Comment: @phood2009, you don't need to have `async` in the base class to be able to add `async` to the overridden methon in the nested class.

Comment: @takemyoxygen thanks for this information. Problem solved. But I have another method. I updated question. That have ref parameter and compiler says "Async methods cannot have ref param.." .

Comment: Does `OnSaveExecuted` method belong to some 3rd party library? In other words, can you change the signature of the method to return some value instead of using `ref` parameter?

Comment: If you can't get rid of the `ref` parameter might be worth providing a synchronous version of `Save` and calling that. It would be the same as blocking on the result, but without the deadlock. Of course you won't get the benefits of it being asynchronous.

Comment: @takemyoxygen yes OnSaveExecuted is on my base class. I can change. I put ActionResult param because I changes ActionResult some where. ActionResult is a reference type but without ref param ActionResult changes doesn't affect.

Comment: @phood2009, you need to explicitly assign then: `actionResult = await someClass.OnSaveExecuted(entity, result)`, but that means that return type of the `OnSaveExecuted` method should be `Task<ActionResult>` even when you don't need to do any asynchonous operations.

Comment: @phood2009, one more thing, I noticed, that you have added `ConfigureAwait(false)` to in your controller, but have you added this to all async methods calls inside `Repository.SaveAsync`? If not, then you should probably do it, it could solve your deadlock issue even without changing signatures of `OnActionExecuted` and `OnSaveExecuted` methods.

Comment: You tried to cheat by blocking on the task. If that was a useful thing to do the framework would just block automatically for you and do this every time.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize things discussed in comments:

- there's no much difference what to use: `Task.Result` or `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - both of them block current thread. To get rid of the deadlock you may keep blocking current thread but you need to ensure that every async call inside `Repository.SaveAsync` doesn't passes its continuation to the current thread, i. e. has `ConfigureAwait(false)`.
- it's better to use `await` instead of blocking the thread. In your case it requires some changes in your base classes methods signatures, so consider implementing both synchronous and asynchronous version of methods. Async operations in MVC don't improve performance or responsiveness of the application (except for high-loaded apps that have many non-CPU operations), so using synchronous operations is just fine.

Comment: Thanks for all information. Actually I using ConfigureAwait(false) in SaveAsync method for all awaitable call. But deadlock still continue. I decided write another method for saving that will be used SaveChanges(). Not Async.